cron jobs to inherit cron daemons environment variable
Let's say, we export an environment variable from the shell,
export A=thisisa

and from the same shell, we start the cron daemon, the shell would then pass the environment variable A to its sub process: cron daemon. Therefore, cron daemon would have access to the environment variable A, making it able to pass the environment variable A to its sub processes which are the tasks started by it. For example sudo has an option -E.
Is there a way to achieve this directly through cron daemon configuration or in a similar efficient manner?
I've found similar questions and answers but they all seemed to describe the way it is done by sourcing a file (such as .bashrc) where environment variables are defined in.

Read man -a crontab you can set environment variables i. your crontab.

@waltinator The technique in the question exports the variable to all users' crontabs, that  only does it for one user at a time.

The following approach was verified on my Debian system. Note that Debian uses the vixie version of cron; some other distros use a different version. I haven't tested this approach on other distros, and YMMV:

open the file /etc/environment in your editor, and add your environment variables; e.g. : ENV_VAR_B=hoppinjohn

Alternatively, from the command line:
$ sudo echo "ENV_VAR_B=hoppinjohn" >> /etc/environment


in your crontab(s), add a statement to print cron's environment to a file (for verification):
* * * * * printenv > /home/seamus/cronenvironment.txt 2>&1


verify the env variable has been added by viewing cronenvironment.txt:
$ cat ~/cronenvironment.txt
HOME=/home/seamus
MAILTO=
LOGNAME=seamus
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
ENV_VAR_B=hoppinjohn
PWD=/home/seamus



